# Como cambiar de un user control a otro tocando un boton en windows forms?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net

estoy en un proyecto que estoy utilizando un unico form, pero con multiples user control que ya estan creados, y ahora quiero moverme desde uno a otro con los botones que estos tienen.

Tengo por ejemplo este user control para registrarse:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesitaria que tocando en link label debajo del todo, poder mostrar en mi form el user control de inicio de sesion, pero no se como hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez `Show()` para mostrar y `Hide()` para ocultar. Por ejem. `textbox1.Show();`

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/358655)

Comment: Los métodos Show y Hide forman parte de la clase Control de Windows Form en el lenguaje de programación C#. Cito: "...poder mostrar en mi form el user control..." eso es justamente lo que trata de resolver mi respuesta.